# Perform equality checks between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, validation, dataframe

I have two data-frames

`df` which contains raw data with the head looking like (this has several thousand records):

```
0   Floor    Dept   .....more fields
1   1        Kitchen
2   1        Electrical
3   2        DIY
4   3        Music
```

`validation` which is a distinct list of which dept is on which floor

```
Floor Dept
G     Food
1     Kitchen
1     Electrical
1     Toys
2     Electrical
3     Music
```

Is there a way to use the `validation` data-frame to check that the right dept is on the right floor in the `df`? Using two valadation columns would be used to check 2 df columns.

So it would catch errors in the `df` like Kitchen being on floor 3 (when in fact its on floor 1)

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could tuplecize your dataframes and do an `isin` check.

```
val = validation.apply(tuple, 1).values
if ~df[['Floor', 'Dept']].apply(tuple, 1).isin(val).all():
    print('Invalid Entries')
```

If you just want to obtain a boolean mask, this should do:

```
mask = df[['Floor', 'Dept']].apply(tuple, 1).isin(val)
```

---

If `validation` has `Floor` as in index, please reset it before the `apply`.

```
val = validation.reset_index().apply(tuple, 1).values
```

Comment: If I understand correctly your concatenating the 'Floor' and 'Dept' in the validation and df dataframes then comparing the two lists? How would I output the invalid entries please? Thx

Comment: @Stacey Very simple. df[~mask]

Answer (score 1):

If validation is looking like that i would first

```
  validation = validation.reset_index()
```

to get the index into column. Then if i got your question correct, try out to merge df and validation

```
  df_validation = pd.merge(validation,df, on=["Floor","Dept"])
```

Try out inner, left and right join for best possible representation. Is that helping you?

Comment: You don't even know what you want OP to do... how is this an answer to the question? What happens after a merge? How are you going validate after that?

Comment: Keep cool. He could try out what I have written and then gradually reach the solution. Anyway, thats obsolete, the solution is above from another user.